# HashMap, Initialization of ArrayList<Point> as values of the map fails

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I've got a class called Point which has a constructor Point that inits x,y.

I've got a map of Point(key) and ArrayList(value),
after initializing the map, my arrayLists are still null, why is that?

```
//Flip objects for the current player's choice
        Map<Point, ArrayList<Point>> flipMap = new HashMap<Point, ArrayList<Point>>();

//Init flipping map with keys
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    flipMap.put(new Point(i,j), new ArrayList<Point>());

ArrayList<Point> test;
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                    if((test = flipMap.get(new Point(i,j))) == null);
                    test = new ArrayList<Point>();
                }
            }
```

**PROBLEM - This prints null:**

```
System.out.println(flipMap.get(new Point(0,0)));
```

Comment: Does your Point class correctly override Object's equals and hashMap methods?

Comment: show us the point class

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Solved now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement hashCode and equals on Key,in your case Point class. The default implementation of these methods simply checks for instance equality (in other words, two Objects will only be equal if they are in fact the same object).In your case when your putting in hash map and fetching you are creating new object,So default implementation will treat as different key.You can verify by size of the hashMap.

**Solution:**

```
 public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the hashcode and equals functions on class Point in order for hashmap properly store and fetchs your values. Otherwise the objects are only equal and returned when they are the exact same object.